# How to add tooltip for an disabled <li> items in angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a li list as follows,

```
<li class="dropdown-item"
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    uib-tooltip="tooltip goes here"
    data-placement="left"
    data-ng-repeat="result in items.results.contextValues.rows "

    data-ng-class="{'disabled': result[3] === 'disable' }"
    >
    {{result[1]}}
</li>
```

And this is my condition for disabling,

```
'disabled': result[3] === 'disable'
```

How to add tooltip on hover when the li elements are disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following `ng-attr-title="{{result[3] === 'disable' ? 'disabled' : undefined}}"` :-

```
<li class="dropdown-item"
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    uib-tooltip="tooltip goes here"
    data-placement="left"
    data-ng-repeat="result in items.results.contextValues.rows "
    ng-attr-title="{{result[3] === 'disable' ? 'disabled' : undefined}}"
    data-ng-class="{'disabled': result[3] === 'disable' }"
    >
    {{result[1]}}
</li>
```

I have created a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kumarshivratn/cwLazp4j/2/) for you. Please have a look.

Comment: Can you please inspect and check if there is a title attribute to the li element?

Comment: according to your code, title I can see is 'disabled'

Comment: pointer-events: none !important;
    background-color: #bbb !important;
    cursor: not-allowed;

Comment: Hmmm, `pointer-events: none` is the culprit here. Because of that browser is not firing the hover event on that element. So, as a work around you should wrap the `li` elements and add the title attribute on the same.

Comment: can you please do it for me.Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer with the fiddle link. please check.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, browsers don't fire mouse events on disabled elements, so the tooltip can never fire. Easy workaround could be wrap the disabled element and show tooltip on it.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no disabled attribute for `li` elements in html.